# python Flask socketio 404/400 from browser

Tags: javascript, python, flask, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to run a flask-socketio server that connects to a react app in the browser.

python Server code (relevant portions):

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on('message')
def handle_message(message):
    print('received message: ' + message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

client js(running in browser):

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:5000");
console.log('connecting to log ws')
ws.onopen = function (event) {
  console.log('connection opened')
};
ws.onmessage = function (event) {
  console.log(event.data);
  self.recieve(event.data);
}
```

I get the following error in the browser:

```
failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

Now I've heard that this is often because I've made a mistake in the url I use. However, when I change

`var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:5000");`

to

`var ws = new WebSocket("wss://127.0.0.1:5000");`

I can see that the server gets the connection request, but it returns the following error on the server side:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Nov/2017 13:07:59] code 400, message Bad HTTP/0.9 request 
type ('\x16\x03\x01\x00t\x01\x00\x00p\x03\x01Y\xfb{\x1f\x0
5\x8d\xbf|\xdb\xeb\x12\xe8\xf6\xb0\xf9')
```

What do i need to do to get a successful connection set up here? The browser used here is chrome, but Im having difficulty with others as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer. You cannot use WebSocket in the browser to communicate with flask-socketio, instead I needed to also use regular socket.io in the client side to communicate with the server. Since switching, I'm getting perfect communication between client and server.

Comment: It can be done using the browser, but if you're using a web based client you need to make sure it uses SocketIO, and not some other implementation. One I have found that works for is http://amritb.github.io/socketio-client-tool/